# Issue with Upvalues

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, upvalues

I want to introduce two variables (I call them EXt and EXtC, where "C" stands for complex conjugate) which would mimic the behavior of a phase of a complex number. For that, I use the following tags:

```
 EXt /: EXt EXtC := 1;
 EXtC /: EXtC EXt := 1;
 EXt /: EXt EXtC^n_ := EXtC^(n - 1);
 EXtC /: EXtC EXt^n_ := EXt^(n - 1);
 EXt /: EXt^(n_?Negative) := EXtC^(-n);
 EXtC /: EXtC^(n_?Negative) := EXt^(-n);
 EXt /: Conjugate[EXt] := EXtC;  
 EXtC /: Conjugate[EXtC] := EXt;
```

With that, I can simplify expressions like

```
EXt^2 EXt^2
```

i.e. when both of the variables have the same power (and this power *is a number*)

However, I am not able to simplify the expressions in which the powers are different. For example, I cannot simplify (i.e. make it equal to EXtC in this case),

```
EXt^2 EXtC^3
```

even with the use of `FullSimplify`. I tried to introduce the following tag

```
EXt /: EXt^n_ EXtC^m_ := EXtC^(m - n)
```

but soon learned (for example, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648260/what-does-upvalue-mean-in-mathematica-and-when-to-use-them)) that the upvalue mechanism can only scan one level deep, so I expectedly get the error message

```
TagSetDelayed::tagpos: Tag EXt in EXt^n_ EXtC^m_ is too deep for an assigned rule to be found. >>
```

Any ideas on how to circumvent this restriction and implement this property?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about the following?:

```
Clear[ext, extc]
ext /: ext[n_] extc[m_] := extc[m - n]
ext /: ext[n_] ext[m_] := ext[m + n]
extc /: extc[n_] extc[m_] := extc[m + n]
ext /: Conjugate@ext[n_] := extc[n]
extc /: Conjugate@extc[n_] := ext[n]
extc[n_?Negative] := ext[-n]
ext[n_?Negative] := extc[-n]
extc[0] = 1;

ext /: Power[ext[m_], n_] := ext[m n]
extc /: Power[extc[m_], n_] := extc[m n]

$Pre = # &;
patt = Except[Clear | ClearAll | Remove];
ext /: (h : patt)[a___, ext, b___] := h[a, ext@1, b]
extc /: (h : patt)[a___, extc, b___] := h[a, extc@1, b]


Format@ext[n_] := EXt^n
Format@extc[n_] := EXtC^n
```

Example:

```
ext
(* EXt *)

ext^2 extc^3
(* EXtC *)

ext extc^n // Conjugate
(* EXt^(-1 + n) *)
```

Comment: One fun thing you could always add is `ext /: Power[ext, n] := ext[n]` which would obviate the need for writing `ext[n]` for powers. Then all you'd need to do would be add some rules on `ext` so that when used in the appropriate context it expands to `ext[1]`  and then you'd get out the behavior the OP wanted. You could even do something like `ext /: (h: Power|Times|...)[a___, ext, b___]:>h[a, ext[1], b])` and then things would be easy

Comment: @b3m2a1 Inspired by your comment, I recalled something interesting. Have a look.

Comment: Edge case that isn't handled: `ext[2]^2`. Also, as usual, using `Format` has an evaluation leak, e.g., `Hold[ext[1+1]]`.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks for pointing out. Fixed.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

Here's a variation of @xzczd's idea, using only a single symbol and adding formatting:

```
Clear[ext]
ext[n_] ext[m_] ^:= ext[n+m]
ext[n_]^m_ ^:= ext[n m]
Conjugate[ext[n_]] ^:= ext[-n]
ext[0] = 1;

MakeBoxes[ext[n_],StandardForm]:=Switch[Unevaluated @ n,
    0, "1",
    1, MakeBoxes[EXt],
    -1, MakeBoxes[EXtC],
    _Integer?Negative, With[{s=-n}, MakeBoxes[EXtC^s]],
    _, MakeBoxes[EXt^n]
]
```

For example:

```
EXt = ext[1]
EXtC = ext[-1]
```

> EXt
>
> EXtC

And:

```
EXt^2 EXtC^2
EXt^2 EXtC^3
EXt EXtC^n //Conjugate
```

> 1
>
> EXtC
>
> EXt^(-1 + n)

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot!